# Is there any way to download Amazon's business report using Amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I am trying to download the 'Detail Page Sales and Traffic' and 'Detail Page Sales and Traffic By Child Item' automatically. Because manual pulling takes extra effort to complete this job. Also **scraping** option is not possible.So if there is any way to pull using MWS Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this report (and many others) are not available via the MWS API. The only reports available via MWS are the ones listed here:

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html